# How to Access Robot Fields Inside a Webots-ROS2 Plugin?

Tags: c++, webots, ros2

I'm running Webots R2023a where I have a robot node marked as *Supervisor* in Webots world (*.wbt file) to be controlled by an external node in ROS2 network. When writing a webots-ros2 plugin, I'm faced with an issue where I cannot access robot fields inside the plugin implementation file.

The `init` function of the plugin provides a `WebotsNode` object which inherits a ROS2 node:

```
init(webots_ros2_driver::WebotsNode *node, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> &parameters)
```

However, I need a reference to the current robot as a `webots::Supervisor` object so I can retrieve nodes and fields of this robot (using the *Supervisor* API methods) to have full control over various aspects of the simulation.

Is it possible to get a handle to the robot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 2023.0.0 of the `webots_ros2` package, the Robot node (or Supervisor or Driver) cannot be accessed anymore. This is due to the fact that the `webots_ros2_driver` package (which defines the `WebotsNode`) doesn't use the C++ API of the libController anymore. Instead it now uses the C API.

Therefore, only the C API can now be used in plugins. You can take a look at the following tutorial: [Creating a Custom C++ Plugin](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/wiki/Tutorial-Creating-a-Custom-Cpp-Plugin) which uses the C API to access the robot devices and apply velocities to its motors.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by:

1. set `SUPERVISOR` to `TRUE` in the WeBots tree for the robot you want to get fields from and save your world (make sure you are saving the actual world and no a cached copy run by ros2 launch)
2. in the `init` function, get the WeBots NODE (not the ROS2 Node) using `.getSelf()` (or `wb_supervisor_node_get_self()`). Save this object off for later use.
3. in your step function (or any of your callbacks; just not the initialization functions) call `.getField`. You can use `wb_supervisor_field_get_count (.getCount)` from there.